# Function by properties

Tags: functions, special-functions

I am looking for a function $f(x)$, which

1. is vertical at the origin ($f'(0)\approx -\infty$)
2. goes to zero further from the origin ($f(x) \to 0$ for $x\to \infty$ and for $x\to -\infty$)
3. and is rotationally symmetric ($f(x) = -f(-x)$ for all $x$)
4. is finite ($\forall x: -\infty \neq f(x)\neq \infty$)
5. is differentiable ($f'(x)$ is not undefined for every $x$)

(visually this will look like one heart beat on a monitor, just to give some idea)

Of course I'd like the function to be the least complex as possible. (Furthermore it would be nice if the function would have some statistical importance.)

Do you know any function satisfying these properties?

How does one go about searching for a function, which has to satisfy such properties?

Is there any application which helps you in finding the right/best function? (Mathematica?)

Comment: 1 and 3 seem contradictory.

Comment: Normally we say that infinite tangent slopes are undefined and that a function is not differentiable at that point. So, some people will find 1 and 5 contradictory. I suppose we're to interpret #5 as allowing infinite slopes, as long as they are the same limit on both sides of $x$?

Comment: I placed #5 so as to exclude the use of functions such as sign(.) and abs(.), since these have **undefined** derivatives, haven't they?

Answer (score 3):

How about $-x^\frac{1}{3} \, e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: You can just negate the function if you'd like the slope to approach $-\infty$. Sorry, I was just concentrating on the vertical part.

Comment: Went ahead and added it for you... but in the future you can and should toss the correction in yourself :)

Comment: @john, is this function used often? Or did you just come up with it? Does the function have a name?

Comment: I just came up with it. $x^{1/3}$ is a simple function which is vertical at $x=0$, while $e^{-x^2}$ is another simple function that (quite dominantly) tends to 0 as $x$ tends to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. Put them together and problem solved! :)

Answer (score 2):

How about
$$
f(x)=-\text{sgn}(x)\,\frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{1+x^2}\text{ ?}
$$
Here $\text{sgn}(x)=1$ if $x>0$, $-1$ if $x<0$ and $0$ if $x=0$. It is not differentiable at $x=0$, but you wanted $f'(0)\approx-\infty$.

More general example:

$$
f(x)=-\text{sgn}(x)\,\frac{|x|^p}{1+|x|^q}\quad 0<p<1,\quad q>p.
$$

Comment: The function you gave me has a derivative that is undefined at $x=0$, but it did inspire me to define $f(x) = \frac{x^{1/p}}{1+x^q}$ where p is an even natural number, and q is an odd one. This latter function has the derivative requirement I stated.

Comment: Which requirement is not satisfied? Also note that your $f$ is not "rotationally symmetric" and is not defined at $x=-1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant: $f(x) = \frac{x^{1/p}}{1+x^q}$, where $p$ is odd and $q$ is even.

Comment: Am I wrong to say your function has an undefined derivative at $x=0$ instead of a derivative of $-\infty$?

Comment: If you use the definition of derivative, you will find the $\lim_{x\to0}(f(x)-0)(x-0)=-\infty$, so in a sense $f'(0)=-\infty$. However, it is usual to say that such a function is not diferentiable at $x=0$. By the way, your corrected $f$ is the same as mine.